# toggle css3 not running

Tags: html, css

I am trying to toggle with css3 but its not working. Anyone have a solution? Why I cant use `input:checked ~` in this case?

Here is my code: https://codeshare.io/axvvZB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.show-more #toggle:checked ~ .toggle-content { ... }
```

> Above selector will work only when `div.toggle-content` will be child of `div.show-more` and placed
>   after `input#toggle` in HTML code.

Your code structure should be:

```
<div class="show-more">
  <label for="toggle">VIEW ALL</label>
  <input id="toggle" type="checkbox" style="visibility:hidden">
  <div class="toggle-content">
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <div class="fade"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.toggle-content {
  height:5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition:all 1s linear;
}

.toggle-content .fade {
  bottom: -20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.show-more {
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  background: #2196F3;
}
.show-more label {
  color: #fff!important;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.show-more #toggle:checked ~ .toggle-content{
  height:auto
}
```

```html
<div class="show-more">
  <label for="toggle">VIEW ALL</label>
  <input id="toggle" type="checkbox" style="visibility:hidden">
  <div class="toggle-content">
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <div class="fade"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the sibling selector in css (`~`) but your elements in markup are not siblings of the `input` element.

You have to make `.toggle-content` the sibling of `#toggle` to get it working.

Refer code:

```css
.toggle-content {
  height: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

.toggle-content .fade {
  bottom: -20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.show-more {
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  background: #2196F3;
}

.show-more label {
  color: #fff!important;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.show-more #toggle:checked ~ .toggle-content {
  height: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="show-more">
  <label for="toggle">VIEW ALL</label>
  <input id="toggle" type="checkbox" style="visibility:hidden">
  <div class="toggle-content">
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <div class="fade"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```